# Programmatically disconnect network connectivity

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, networking

Is there a way to programmatically and temporarily disconnect network connectivity in .NET 4.0?

I know I can get the current network connectivity status by doing this...

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

but for testing purposes I would like test my application's behavior when it loses network connectivity (without physically unplugging the network cable).

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Just unplug the dang thing. :)

Comment: Yes, I realize I could unplug the network cable. But like I said in my question, I would like to programmatically disconnect the network to aid in testing connected and disconnected functionality in the application.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do it with WMI.  Here's one we use for disabling the physical adapter to test these types of scenarios.

```
using System.Management;
using System.Linq;

namespace DisableNIC
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var wmiQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter " +
                                            "WHERE NetConnectionId != null " +
                                              "AND Manufacturer != 'Microsoft' ");
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery))
            {
                foreach (var item in searcher.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>())
                {
                    if ((string) item["NetConnectionId"] != "Local Area Connection")
                        continue;

                    using (item)
                    {
                        item.InvokeMethod("Disable", null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You didn't indicate the OS, but this works in Windows 7 and Windows 8.

**Note** that you will need to be an administrator for this to function.

Comment: I like it. Elegant, precise, and you didn't tell me to unplug my network cable :-)

Comment: Side note: This method requires admin rights on Windows 7 (and probably also Windows 8 and Windows Vista)

Answer (score 1):

if you use 'Managed Wifi API' you can simply delete the profile. That worked for me.

```
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();

WlanClient.WlanInterface m_WlanInterface = client.Interfaces.Where(i => i.InterfaceDescription.Contains(InterfaceIdentifierString)).First();
m_WlanInterface.DeleteProfile(ConnectionProfileString);
```

If you need to reconnect to that network, be sure to save the xml profile:

```
string xmlString = m_WlanInterface.GetProfileXml(ConnectionProfileString)
```

Then you can reuse it

```
 m_WlanInterface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, xmlString, true);
 m_WlanInterface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, ConnectionProfileString);
```