# How to establish dial-up internet connection

Tags: c#, networking, windows-7, usb, modem

I have a Nokaia 3G USB modem (stick) that I want to turn on and off programmatically.

This modem installs itself in Windows 7 as just another network adapter - no new modems are added.

Because no modem is added I cannot use RAS to establish connection from code, as I can (and do) with many other 3G USB modem sticks.

In the Network Connections window the network adapter looks like a **WLAN** adapter (you know, with those "signal strength bars" in the icon), and by right-clicking it i am able to do the connect/disconnect action interactively.

But how can I establsh connection **from code** with this modem? I'm sure there must be a simple way...?

Answer (score 1):

What you are really asking is, how to enable or disable a network connection. You can do this using WMI as shown in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244496/c-sharp-programmatically-disconnect-network-connectivity), to enable or disable the card, using the appropriate methods of the [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class. You can check, but not change, the connection status by reading the NetConnectionStatus property.

In your case you should probably use a query like:

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Manufacturer == 'Nokaia' "
```

or whatever the actual manufacturer name is. Querying by name is not guaranteed to work, as the user can change the name of the connection.

Also check "[How can I tell if a wireless network is connected](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/08/20/how-can-i-tell-if-a-wireless-network-adapter-is-connected-to-the-network.aspx)" on Technet for a more thorough description of how to use Win32_NetworkAdapter.

Comment: @Panagoiotis Kanavos: No, I **don't** ask how to enable or disable, I actually ask how to change the **connection staus** (establish and tear down the connection). I'm sorry if I have not made myself clear in my original question.

Comment: for change status connection you want to use [Networkchange Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx) but I don't know if it's Okay, with Dial-up Key.