# C# code to connect/disconnect the internet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - programmatically disconnect network connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244496/c-sharp-programmatically-disconnect-network-connectivity)

I need to make an application that connect/disconnect the internet every ten minutes..

Comment: What's the use case for this? Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about shell command:

`rasdial.exe <connName> <userName> <password>`

Comment: This command doesn't even come close to what the author wanted.